# Cloudflare wrangler tail --format pretty: Error parsing response body

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

When using `wrangler tail --format pretty`, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing response body!
This is not a problem with your worker, it's a problem with Wrangler.
Please file an issue on our GitHub page, with a minimal reproducible example of
the script that caused this error and a description of what happened.
```

Its quite difficult for me to upload the JSON from `wrangler tail --format json` to a Github issue as mentioned in the error message, because it comprises of the entire request details, which includes my post code, latitude, longitude, though I am not sure why there is so much personal information in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution I found was to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead of using `wrangler tail --format pretty`:

On macOS,

- Install jq: `brew install jq`
- Pipe wrangler output into jq with: `wrangler tail --env environment_name | jq`